# How to send complex object to blazor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to forward a complex object to one blazor page from another. Lets consider the following three classes.

```
public class Order
{
    
    public Supplier { get; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>();
    public decimal TotalValue { get; set; }
    
    public Order(Supplier supplier)
    {
        Supplier = supplier;
    }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryConditions { get; set; }
    public int PaymentConditions { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have two pages. The first one allows the user to selected a supplier and creates an object of type Order based on the supplier. The second page should work with this object and should allow the user to edit all other order details, except for the supplier.

In my case I need to select the supplier first in order to be able to filter out all products which cannot be delivered by the supplier.

How could I achive this?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds promising: https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-singleton-pass-data-between-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about using a singleton service? This can be used on all pages by use of @inject and as a singleton. You can set supplier and order it in the page where the supplier is selected and the order is generate. And also inject it on the other pages.

```
public class OrderService{
    public Order ActiveOrder {get;private set;}
    public Supplier ActiveSupplier {get;set;}
    public void GenerateOrder(Supplier s) {
        //...
    }
}
```

You must register the Service in Startup as singleton:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<OrderService>();
```

So you can use this in your pages like:

```
@inject OrderService MyOrderService​
private void SupplierSelected(Supplier s)
{
    MyOrderService.GenerateOrder(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the parameter keyword, the first component will load to the second one when it has the data:
In the example you put the first page will be the supplier, and when its complete you pass it as a parameter:

```
@using Pages
@page "/"

<h1>First supplier page</h1>


<label> Supplier Id</label>
<input @bind="@sup.SupplierId" type="int"/>


<button @onclick="() => this.done=true"> Submit </button>


@if(done) { 
    
    <product supplier="sup"></product>
}

@code{
public bool done=false;
Supplier sup = new();    


}
```

Here you can see how pass the supplier as parameter to the second blazor component.
In this page you can use your object as you want.

```
@using Pages
<h3>Second page with supplier as parameter</h3>

//whatever presentation
@code {
        [Parameter]
    public Supplier supplier{ get; set; }

    //whatever logic
}
```